# Download Mono-Complete

Tags: 14.04, mono

**I want to Download (not install) Mono-complete for ubuntu 14.04 as well as ubuntu 12.04 .**

- Please Suggest How can i download? (my goal is to install it later on
  other system without internet. )
- And which mono-complete version is best suited for ubuntu 14.04 and
  for ubuntu 12.04 platform.so that it gives complete/satisfactory
  memory management or garbage collection.
- When i run .Net AppLication by Mono-Complete version 3.2.8 downloaded
  from synaptic ,it runs the application but gives mono-sgen crashed
  with SIGABRT error.But on the same lines when i run application from
  Sudo application runs but it does not crash but red circle comes on
  the desktop.I used modern dlls in my application

Answer (score 1):

A list of applicable sources to install can be find here:
http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mono-complete

A other way is to go the Term way and installing the package of your desire using sudo commands: sudo apt-get install mono-complete

add repo if you do not got it:echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list

update & update using sudo apt-get update

Enjoy your .net platform framework!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the **apt-offline** utility to install packages on systems without an internet connection. The advantage of it is that it automatically takes care of dependencies and even works across different systems, e.g. I can use my Mint 17.2 (based on 14.04) to fetch packages for a Kubuntu 13.10. apt-offline uses a three step process.

But first you have to install apt-offline on both the offline and online system. For the online system, you can simply do

```
sudo apt-get install apt-offline
```

For the offline system, you may now simply take the package from the online system's cache at `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and install it. All dependencies are already installed (python, apt, less). Should it not work, e.g. due to having a really old system, you can get older versions of the package from  [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/apt-offline/) (for current Ubuntu's) or [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/apt-offline/) (for EOL Ubuntu's). Take the Debian archive to the offline computer and install it.

---

## The three step process

1. At the offline computer, enter the command

   ```
    apt-offline set --install-packages <package1> <package2> ... <packageN>
   ```

   This will generate a file called `apt-offline.sig`. Take this file over to your online computer. Should you be running an old release, make sure, APT's sources.list point to the [old-releases server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release). In this case, this may require internet for a single `apt-get update`, afterwards never again.
2. At the online computer, cd to the signature file and run the command

   ```
    apt-offline get
   ```

   this will download the required packages and their dependencies. Take all downloaded files back to the offline computer.
3. At the offline computer, cd to the folder with the archives in and run

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   Actually apt-offline intends the 3rd step to be done differently, but I found this way to work better.

In this way, you can not only install Mono on an offline computer, but you have a semi-automated way of installing any package on offline debian-based systems.